# Как вывести корректно слайдер с помощью handlebars ?

Tags: javascript, json, handlebars

Есть блок с текстом и заголовком, он корректно выводиться, но мне нужно в этом блоке расположить слайдер, сам слайдер работает, **НО**,  он выводит все картинки как отдельный объект, вот так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот блок, где расположен слайдер, текст и прочее:

```
<!-- Why Choose Us -->
<div id="{{block_id}}" class="section md-padding bg-grey">

    <!-- Container -->
    <div class="container">

        <!-- Row -->
        <div class="row">

            <!-- why choose us content -->
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="section-header">
                    <h2 class="title">{{header}}</h2>
                </div>
                <p>{{text}}</p>
        {{#each_with_sort about "order"}}
                <div class="feature">
                    <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
                    <p>{{text}}</p>
                </div>
{{/each_with_sort}}

            </div>
            <!-- /why choose us content -->

            <!-- About slider -->
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div id="about-slider" class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
            {{#each_with_sort slider "order"}}
                    <img class="img-responsive" src="{{image}}" alt="">
        {{/each_with_sort}}
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- /About slider -->

        </div>
        <!-- /Row -->

    </div>
    <!-- /Container -->

</div>
<!-- /Why Choose Us -->
```

Вот файл json, где есть все значения:

```
{
  "groups": "features",
  "template": "template.hbs",
  "settings": [{
      "name": "block_id",
      "label": "Block's id",
      "type": "text"
    },{
        "name": "header",
        "label": "Block's header",
        "type": "text",
        "placeholder": "Header"
    },{
      "name": "text",
      "label": "Text",
      "type": "text",
      "placeholder": "text"
    },{
      "name": "about",
      "label": "About",
      "type": "accordion",
      "settings": [{
          "name": "text",
          "label": "Text",
          "type": "text",
          "placeholder": "Text"
        }]
    },{
      "name": "slider",
      "label": "Slider",
      "type": "accordion",
      "settings": [{
          "name": "image",
          "label": "image",
          "type": "image"
        }]
    }

  ],
  "defaults": {
    "block_id": "features",
    "header": "Why Choose Us",
    "text":  "Molestie at elementum eu facilisis sed odio. Scelerisque in dictum non consectetur a erat. Aliquam id diam maecenas ultricies mi eget mauris. Ultrices sagittis orci a scelerisque purus.",
    "about": [{
        "text": "Quis varius quam quisque id diam vel quam elementum.",
        "order": 1
    },{
        "text": "Mauris augue neque gravida in fermentum.",
        "order": 2
    },{
        "text": "Orci phasellus egestas tellus rutrum.",
        "order": 3
    },{
        "text": "Nec feugiat nisl pretium fusce id velit ut tortor pretium.",
        "order": 4
    }],
    "slider": [{
        "image": "%block_url%/img/about1.jpg",
        "order": 1
    },{
        "image": "%block_url%/img/about2.jpg",
        "order": 2
 },{
        "image": "%block_url%/img/about1.jpg",
        "order": 3
 },{
        "image": "%block_url%/img/about2.jpg",
        "order": 4
 }
]}
}
```

Буду благодарен любой помощью или просто содействию, спасибо.

Comment: Подключили ли вы все необходимые js и css для слайдера?

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko Да, я же говорю слайдер сам работает, но картинки он отображает как один объект. он не разделяет и получается все слито.

Comment: Да, я же спрашиваю, подключили ли вы все необходимые скрипты js-файла и стили css-файлы, которые требует данный слайдер?